# JavaScript object - convert to JSON format and pass to a server side function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

With the below code we can store our client side data in dictionary like object through JavaScript:

```
var Person = {};
Person["EmployeeID"] = "201";
Person["Name"] = "Keith";
Person["Department"] = "Sales";
Person["Salary"] = "25000";
```

Now I want to know how could I convert the `Person` object to JSON format and pass to our server side function and client side person object should serialize to server side person object.

My server side function looks like:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Save(Person msg)
{

}
```

So please guide me how to convert the client side person object to JSON format as a result I can send the person data to our server side function with jQuery.

Comment: Not really related, however that's a really long way of assigning an object!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the easy way would be to use jQuery's JSON plug-in and say `$.toJSON(Person)`.

Comment: +1 I was going to say `JSON.stringify(Person)` but the OP did say jQuery, and, well `toJSON` doesn't rely on modern browsers.